# SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpql, hibernate-mapping

I have a spring boot application with an h2 database that is addressed by a CrudRepository.

```
public interface PetRepository extends CrudRepository<PetBE, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM PetBE p INNER JOIN TagBE t WHERE t.name IN :tags")
    public List<PetBE> findPetsByAnyTag(@Param("tags") List<String> tags);
}
```

My Entities are as follows

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "pets")
public class PetBE {
    
    @Id
    private long id;

    @NonNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CategoryBE category;
    
    @NonNull
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> photoUrls;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "pet_tags", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pet_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    @OrderColumn(name = "id")
    private List<TagBE> tags;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StatusEnum status;

}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class TagBE {

    @Id
    @NonNull
    private long id;
    
    @NonNull
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToMany
    private List<PetBE> pets;
    
}
```

But when I call my method I get:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select petbe0_.id as id1_4_, petbe0_.category_id as category4_4_, petbe0_.name as name2_4_, petbe0_.status as status3_4_ from pets petbe0_ inner join tags tagbe1_ on where tagbe1_.name in (?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT PETBE0_.ID AS ID1_4_, PETBE0_.CATEGORY_ID AS CATEGORY4_4_, PETBE0_.NAME AS NAME2_4_, PETBE0_.STATUS AS STATUS3_4_ FROM PETS PETBE0_ INNER JOIN TAGS TAGBE1_ ON WHERE[*] TAGBE1_.NAME IN (?)"; expected "NOT, EXISTS, INTERSECTS, UNIQUE"; SQL statement:
select petbe0_.id as id1_4_, petbe0_.category_id as category4_4_, petbe0_.name as name2_4_, petbe0_.status as status3_4_ from pets petbe0_ inner join tags tagbe1_ on where tagbe1_.name in (?) [42001-200]
```

I don't know where to go from here the grammar looks fine to me.
Also the query does compile, the error comes only at runtime.
What am I missing here?

Comment: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/jpql-inner-join.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By not using the defined relationship you're introducing the cross join (but inner join is expected). You can see it in the following fragment of the generated query:

```
inner join tags tagbe1_ on where tagbe1_.name in (?)
                           ^
```

You can fix this by using the second entity as the field of the first one:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM PetBE p INNER JOIN p.tags t WHERE t.name IN :tags")
public List<PetBE> findPetsByAnyTag(@Param("tags") List<String> tags);
```